# using std::move to move the value_type of a map into a vector prevents my Draw function from working

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an object that has a number of data fields

```
class Object{
   Texture texture;
   glm::vec2 Position, Size;
   glm::vec3 Colour;

   //constructor goes here

   virtual void Draw(ObjectRenderer &render);
};
```

I define the draw function as such:

```
void Object::Draw(ObjectRenderer &render)
{
    renderer.DrawObj(this->Sprite, this->Position, this->Size,   this->Colour);
}
```

My ObjectRenderer class has a draw function that takes these parameters

```
void DrawObj(Texture &texture, glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 size, glm::vec3 colour);
```

Later in my code I insert an Object instantion into a vector and attempt to render it onto an openGL context.

```
vector<Object*> cntr;

cntr.push_back(Object obj);
cntr->Draw(*Render);
```

Now this works, and the Object is rendered onto the screen successfully. (Within a game loop). Ok, here is where it gets complicated.

I then take this vector and insert it into a map.

```
map<std::string, std::vector<Object*>> mapCntr;
map.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Object*>>("objectCntr", cntr));
```

When my program is at this state, I can access the value_type of the map container, which is where the vector is stored, and draw an element within that vector.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Object*>>::iterator it;


for (it = cntr.begin(); it != cntr.end(); it++)
{
    if (it->first == "objectCntr")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != it->second.size(); i++)
        {
            it->second[i]->Draw(*Renderer);
        }
    } 
}
```

However here is where the problem occurs. Later in my code I have to take the object that is in the vector that is in the map, and place it into a temporary container. I choose my temporary container to be a vector:

```
vector<Object*> tmpCntr;
```

And I then move the Object into the temporary vector:

```
int i = cntr.find("objectCntr")->second.size() - 1;
tempCntr.push_back(std::move(cntr.find("objectCntr")->second[i]));
```

This move is successful, and I can access the data fields within the object that is stored in the temporary vector.

However I can no longer render the object onto the screen. I have tried the following code:

```
tempCntr[0]->Draw(*Renderer);
```

Nothing works. Yet I know that the Object is in the tempCntr. And if I remove the Object and place it back into the vector that is in the map it renders once again.

Could somebody please suggest what may be the reason why it isn't rendering? Should I use a different type of temporary container instead?

Comment: "using std::move to **copy**" something seems wrong here. You are aware that the state of the object in `cntr` is in some weird state after this?

Comment: sorry, poor choice of language. I really mean move, as in move the object entirely.

Comment: Does it work if you make a copy instead of moving it?

Comment: Since the elements are just pointers you really should just copy them.  copying a pointer is no big deal.